# even when making money is a problem

Tags: word-usage

> When making money is not a problem for a company, making money is a means, and the  dream is the aim. However, even when making money is a problem, making money itself is the aim.

Can I use even to emphasize the time the company have difficulty in making money?

Comment: No.  "Even" would only work there if making money were not the aim: "When X, Y. However, even when not X [also] Y."

Comment: "*While* making money..." in the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

No, in this case "even" suggests that the result is the same *even when* circumstances are different.  You're better off removing it.

However, overall this sentence reads like a deliberate *play on words*, given the repetition of the "m" sound: *"making" "money" "means" "aim" "dream" "problem"* etc.  If so, and it's more about *style* than substance, it's fine -- but otherwise it's difficult to understand what you are trying to say.